# Android Studio and Flutter(VSCode) show the same problem sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.isCurveSupported([B)Z

Tags: android-studio, flutter, windows-10, build.gradle

Im currently developing an android app with flutter using VScode. So this problem happened after i update my windows from 1903 to 1909 yesterday. I tried to run and debug my app in vscode it shows:

"**sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.isCurveSupported([B)Z**".

the same thing happen with Android Studio when im trying to test my code. Even the gradle sync in android studio failed with the same message (see the image below):

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVe70.png)

Comment: May [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8233954) be helpful?

Comment: i have removed the sunec.dll, reinstall java jdk but the problem still didnt resolved.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I am having the same issue with Android Studio, but I can't even find out where it has its JDK installed nowadays

Comment: @robert  I finally reset the Windows and reinstall all of the software, and then the problem is gone.

Comment: On Mac have the same problem.